# Showing $f_n$ does not converge uniformly

Tags: real-analysis

If we let $f_n(x)=\frac{x^2+nx}{n}$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$. I have proved that $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f(x)=x$

Now I am trying to prove that $f_n$ does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$

$$|f_n(x)-f(x) | = \sup\left|\frac{x^2+nx}{n}-x\right| = \sup \left|\frac {x^2}{n}\right|\rightarrow0$$

Comment: The problem in your last step is that $$\sup_{x\in\Bbb R}\frac{x^2}n$$ is **not** finite so its limit when $\;n\to\infty\;$ isn't zero, as needed to have *uniform* convergence.

Comment: so this solution and logic is incorrect?

Comment: @DonAntonio how is limit not 0?

Comment: Before taking the limit you **must have** the supremum, which is.... There you go!!

Comment: @DonAntonio looking at the answer that has been provided, does my comment to this answer make sense?

Answer (score 3):

Let $\epsilon=1$.  Then, for any $n$, we select $x=\sqrt{n}$ and find that

$$\left|\frac{x^2+nx}{n}-x\right|=\left|\frac{x^2}{n}\right|\ge 1$$

Comment: does this prove along with my answer provided that it is not uniformly convergent? in my answer I have said that the limit must go to 0. but this answer you have provided shows a contradiction so its not uniformly convergent?

Comment: @user284 In your question you put some strange things, like "...using the fact that $\;x^2\rightarrow\sqrt n\;$ " (??), and then some $\;x_n\;$ ...(?). I think the above answer is what you need in the spirit of what you wanted. +1

Comment: @user284 This is precisely the negation of uniform convergence for $x\in\mathbb{R}$.